# NSString drawAtPoint on a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a subclassed UITextView for placeholder and background image.

Here's the code

***BKCUTextView.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BKCUTextView : UITextView
- (void)setPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder;
- (void)setPlaceholderColor:(UIColor *)placeholderColor;
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)img;
@end
```

***BKCUTextView.m***

```
#import "BKCUTextView.h"
@interface BKCUTextView()
{
    NSString    * _placeholder;
    UIColor     * _normalColor;
    UIColor     * _placeholderColor;
    BOOL        _needToShowPlaceholder;
    UIImageView * _bgImageView;
}
@end

@implementation BKCUTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self _initEvents];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if(_needToShowPlaceholder)   {   [_placeholder drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withFont:self.font];    }
}

- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor
{
    _normalColor = textColor;
}

- (void)setPlaceholderColor:(UIColor *)placeholderColor
{
    _placeholderColor = placeholderColor;
}

- (void)setPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder
{
    _needToShowPlaceholder = YES;
    _placeholder = placeholder;
}

-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    if(_bgImageView == nil)
    {
        _bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        [self addSubview:_bgImageView];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:_bgImageView];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    [_bgImageView setImage:img];
}

- (void)_initEvents
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_textChanged:) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:self];
}

-(void)_textChanged:(NSNotification *)noti
{
    _needToShowPlaceholder = (self.text.length == 0);
    if(_needToShowPlaceholder)  {   self.textColor = _placeholderColor; }
    else                        {   self.textColor = _normalColor;      }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

***instance***

```
BKCUTextView * tv = [[BKCUTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 55, 300, 50)];
[tv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[tv setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[tv setPlaceholderColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[tv setPlaceholder:@"placeholder here!"];
[tv setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_coin_prs.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:tv];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:tv];
```

each property - backgroundImage and placeholderText - works fine, but when I set them together, the placeholder is drawn under the backgroundImage.

How can I bring the text above the back image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method `[self bringSubviewToFront:];`

Hope it will help!

Comment: UITextView.text = `your string`. And bring uitextview to front

Comment: It doesn't make any senese. This is the Subclass of UITextView and it draws a placeholder text. The property backimage is a subview of the UITextView and it's under the UITextView. bring UITextView to front will not change anythig

Comment: use it in `- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)img` method after you add backgroundImage

Comment: it's not working.  
`-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    [self sendSubviewToBack:_bgImageView];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self];
    [_bgImageView setImage:img];
}`

Comment: `[self bringSubviewToFront:UITEXTVIEW];` not self;

Comment: It's a subclass of UITextView. It means that self is the UITextView class. Do you mean I call it at its superview?

Comment: I tried and still not working. I tried to draw the background image with drawAtRect: and seemed to work perfectly, before I found the drawn image was scrolled up with UITextView's content...